# How to make marginenote text fully justified?

Tags: marginnote

This MWE example, compiled with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[letterpaper,outer=1.8in,bindingoffset=6mm,top=1in,bottom=.85in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\marginnote{\blindtext}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried add this line before the command `\renewcommand*{\raggedrightmarginnote}{\centering}` and get this (still not fully justified )

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried the commands shown on page 2 of the documentation, but now I get an error

[image: Mathematica graphics]

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\framed{%
\let\marginnoteleftadjust\FrameSep
\let\marginnoterightadjust\FrameSep
}
\endgroup

\usepackage[letterpaper,outer=1.8in,bindingoffset=6mm,top=1in,bottom=.85in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\marginnote{\blindtext}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

error is

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def))))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \framed 

l.11 }

?
```

I would have expected the side margin note to be fully justified by default as in the main text. How to fix this?

TL 2015, lualatex compiler.

[https://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote?lang=en)

**Update**

Thanks for comments below. I tried one of the suggestions, but for somereason I get an error. May be I am doing something wrong. I am newbie in advanced Latex programming.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand\mymarginnote[1]{\marginnote{\justify #1}}

\usepackage[letterpaper,outer=1.8in,bindingoffset=6mm,top=1in,bottom=.85in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\mymarginnote{\blindtext}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Compiled with lualatex

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(./foo.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...te \strut \hspace {\z@ }\ignorespaces \justify 
                                                  \blindtext \endgraf \vss }...
l.10 \Blindtext

?
```

Comment: Usually, I define a `\newcommand\mymarginnote[1]{\marginnote{\justify #1}}` for this.

Comment: the width of the margin note is very small, and justifying it could make it much harder to read.  i would definitely *not* expect it to be justified; ragged right is a reasonable decision.  if you *must* set it justified, you can try inserting `\rightskip=0pt\relax` in the note.

Comment: Referring to the `Undefined control sequence.`: I believe that you require the `framed` package ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not recommend to justify text in such a small note.

To justify the margin note you can use

```
\renewcommand\raggedrightmarginnote{}
\renewcommand\raggedleftmarginnote{}
```

But then you will get many overfull or underfull boxes:

[image]

Or you could use

```
\renewcommand\raggedrightmarginnote{\sloppy}
\renewcommand\raggedleftmarginnote{\sloppy}
```

Then you will get big gaps in your notes:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand\raggedrightmarginnote{\sloppy}
\renewcommand\raggedleftmarginnote{\sloppy}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[letterpaper,outer=1.8in,bindingoffset=6mm,top=1in,bottom=.85in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\marginnote{\blindtext}
\Blindtext\marginnote{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

---

Off topic: An example with Comic Sans for Johannes_B ;-)

[image]

Comment: The result might be less awful if typeset with Comic Sans?

Comment: @Johannes_B There is now an example for you ;-) Da schauen die Lücken doch gleich weniger schlimm aus, oder?

Comment: Oh indeed, nice :-)

Comment: With `microtype` and slightly wider margin notes with a slightly smaller font size the result actually looks quite good: a solid rectangle of text on the left (main text) and solid rectangles of texts on the right (margin notes).